# Substring from string oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have strings : `'A-20-1-1', 'A-10-10', 'A-10-11-1'`

And result from substringing:

```
'A-20-1-1', 'A-10-10', 'A-10-11-1'
      1           10         11
```

Code won't works fine:

```
Select Substr(string, instr(string,'-',1,2)+1, instr(string, '-',1,2)-1)
From dual;
```

Comment: Question seems not clear

Comment: Do you want to have the value after the last `-` sign?

Comment: after second '-' sign. strings can have three '-' signs.

Comment: `regexp_substr(string, '[^-]+', 1, 3)` [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8b3d/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I find the second `-` sign position, and then get a substring of the value from this position to the rest of the value. Then I exclude the part of the string from previous step if the string has the `-` sign. Like this:

```
with t(d) as (
  select 'A-20-1-1' from dual union all
  select 'A-10-10-4' from dual union all
  select 'A-10-11-1' from dual 
)
select REPLACE(SUBSTR(d, INSTR(d, '-', 1, 2) + 1), SUBSTR(d, INSTR(d, '-', 1, 3))) from t

RES
---
  1
 10
 11
```

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning I find second '-', than next one if exists. If not I get string length.

```
create table a(b varchar2(20));

insert into a values('A-20-1-1');
insert into a values('A-10-10');
insert into a values('A-10-11-1');


Select 
b, 
substr(b,instr(b,'-',1,2)+1,decode(instr(b,'-',1,3),0,length(b)-instr(b,'-',1,2),instr(b,'-',1,3)-instr(b,'-',1,2)-1)) z
from a;
```

gives us what you need:

```
A-20-1-1    1
A-10-10     10
A-10-11-1   11
```